# DB Connection Pool Size Reasonable Limit?

Tags: asp.net, sql, connection-pooling

Our pool size is set to 600 connections for our web app to our database. However I just got an email from the client saying they are pushing our training course to 4000+ users telling them that they should get it completed by the 27th of this month. Should I up it to 4000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remember having 4000 users doing stuff in the system accessing at different times in a period of 8 hours, isn't the same as having a load of 4000 concurrent users.

Also, unless there are some issues with how the data access is implemented, you really shouldn't be needing to up that. It really depends on the type load + architecture + [insert other factors]. The best would be to do some load testing. Also consider getting performance/resource usage information on the current load, and doing some transaction cost based analysis.

Answer (score 0):

No, connection pool manages connections for you.

in your code, when you close a connection, it returns to pool and used by other requester.

I try to say that, your connection size does not have to equal to user count. Default connection pool size is 100, then your connection pool size is (600) enough, I think.